# Como chamar duas tabelas mysql na mesma pagina php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, aplicação-web

Sou novato na área de programação pra web, e to com dificuldade nisso.
Estou desenvolvendo um site de propaganda e preciso chamar mais de uma tabela na pagina.

Fiz 3 Div's de propaganda: Principais, Gratuitas e geral.

Só consigo mostrar as propagandas da pricipais, a da gratuitas e gerais eu não consigo.

Como estou chamando a principais:

```
<?php
while ($dados=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
?>

<?php echo $dados['site']?> <br>
<?php echo $dados['descricao']?> <br>
<img src="Painel/fotos/<?php echo $dados['foto']?> /><br>

<?php }?>
```

Tento fazer o mesmo para as outras duas Div's e não consigo, tem como me ajudar?

Comment: Mostra o exemplo com duas e com a query SQL.

Comment: Explique o que é "não consigo". Dá erro? Qual? Um detalhe importante, principalmente pra você que é iniciante, é que funções mysql_* estão obsoletas desde o PHP 5.5. Use MySQLi ou PDO. Veja mais aqui: http://www.ultimatephp.com.br/php-por-que-nao-utilizar-funcoes-mysql

Comment: Para 'combinar' tabelas no sql você precisa de um `join` ou `union`.

Comment: Estou pegando os dados do bando assim:

        <?php
 include ("conexao.php");
 $sql="select * from principal";
        $res= mysql_query ($sql);
 ?>

Eu coloco as outras duas tabelas e não da.

Comment: Experimenta fazer com $sql1, $sql2 e $sql3 e $res1 $res2 e $res3.

Comment: Blz vou tentar, obrigado

Answer (score 1):

É só copiar este código para as outras div, com um mysql_query e um mysql_fetch_array pra cada uma. Com o mysql_query vc obteve os dados pra essa né ? então.. obtenha os dados para cada tabela nas outras divs

Edit:

ou seja:

```
<?php 
    include ("conexao.php"); 

    $sql="select * from principal"; $res= mysql_query ($sql); 
    while ($dados=mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
        echo $dados['site'] . "<br>";
        echo $dados['descricao'] . "<br>";
?>
<img src="Painel/fotos/<?php echo $dados['foto']?> /><br>

<?php } ?>
    <br><br>
<?php 
    $sql="select * from gratuitas"; $res= mysql_query ($sql);
    while ($dados=mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
        echo $dados['site'] . "<br>";
        echo $dados['descricao'] . "<br>";
        ?>
    <img src="Painel/fotos/<?php echo $dados['foto']?> /><br>

<?php } ?>
    <br><br>
<?php 

    $sql="select * from geral"; $res= mysql_query ($sql); 
    while ($dados=mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
        echo $dados['site'] . "<br>";
        echo $dados['descricao'] . "<br>";
    ?>
    <img src="Painel/fotos/<?php echo $dados['foto']?> /><br>

<?php }
?>
```

Não testei esse código, pode ter algum erro de sintaxe. Corrija se houver. O código acima é pra dar uma idéia do que quero dizer.

Comment: Tem como ser mais especifico?

Comment: tem... mostre o código onde vc faz o mysql_query e eu complemento

Comment: <?php
include ("conexao.php");
$sql="select * from principal";
$res= mysql_query ($sql);
?>

Comment: Ok vou testar, e vlw

Comment: Funcionou, vlw mesmo.

Comment: Então se puder aceitar a resposta, auxilia :)

Comment: Fiz simples assim, pq vc mesmo disse que era iniciantes em programação web. Esse código pode ser escrito de formas BEM melhores. Procure melhorá-lo depois que estiver com mais experiência.